# Configure HTTPS proxy in Java

Tags: java, https, proxy

For some API calls I need to configure a HTTPS proxy.

Locally I can achieve this with the simple configuration of `Systemproperties` like this:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", HOST);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort",PORT);
```

But that doesn't work when I try this on the code which will be deployed to a WildFily instance. I tried using Unirest, but this only offers HTTP proxy settings which won't work since i need HTTPS:

```
Unirest.setProxy(new HttpHost("94.100.132.14", 80));
HttpResponse<InputStream> response = Unirest.get(url).asBinary();
```

Is there any possibility to configure a HTTPS proxy with unirest or some similar libraries?

Comment: Hi Tobias, Have you tried looking into Zuul ?

Comment: Hi, no, that's the first time I heard of it. I am now running out of options though.. tried everything the past two days.